# How do I apply the same effect that "background-size: cover" does, on a <img>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need a `<img>` to have the smallest possible size without leaving any blank spaces inside a div and it needs to be centralized horizontally and vertically. The size of the image is variable.

So here is an example so you can understand it better:
http://jsfiddle.net/q2c9D/

More info: much like Mikel Ward did, I need the images to fill up the `div`, so that the background of it is *not* visible. I made the `div` background black so it was easier to tell that it is not filling up the `div`. But I need the images to be centered *and* to be the smallest size possible without being distorted while filling up the `div`.

Comment: Please clarify your question and add some code. It is very difficult to understand what you want right now

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. The code is right there on jsfiddle. I want the images to fill the 100x100 size without being distorted (that meaning, keeping the original aspect ratio) and being centralized.

Comment: It looks like you have already accomplished this

Comment: No, as you can see, the second image leaves a blank spot, and none of them is centered.

Comment: I still have no idea what you are trying to do. The images are all 100px tall and wide, so they are already centered

Comment: Independently of the image being wider than taller or taller than wider, I need it to use all the space inside the `div`. I don't know how to explain it better than this. The image has to be re sized to fit inside the `div` and, if necessary, overflow, but while being centered, not leaving any of the background of the `div` visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was able to get it working the way I wanted using jQuery. With the following code:

```
function centerimg(){
```

`$('img').each(function(){
    var imgwidth = $(this).width();
    var imgheight = $(this).height();

    if (imgwidth > imgheight) {
        $(this).css({
            "height": "100%",
            "width": "auto"
        });

        imgwidth = $(this).width();
        $(this).css("margin-left", -.5 * imgwidth + 50 + "px");

    } else if (imgheight > imgwidth) {
        $(this).css({
            "width": "100%",                
            "height": "auto"
        });

        imgheight = $(this).height();
        $(this).css("margin-top", -.5 * imgheight + 50 + "px");

    } else {
        $(this).css({
            "height": "100%",
            "width": "100%"
        })
    }
})

};

window.onload = centerimg;<code>`

The code gets the width and height of the image, so if the image is wider or taller it will properly set the smaller dimension to `100%` and the larger one to `auto`. After that it gets the value of that last one again (since it was re sized with `auto`) and centers it. Also, if the image is a square it just sets both to `100%`.
This way the image will ALWAYS fill up the `div` and be centered.
Thanks all. Hope this code helps others.

Answer (score 2):

[Here is my go](http://jsfiddle.net/q2c9D/5/)

I would set the `width` to 100%, and remove the `height` property altogether. This will prevent the image from being distorted

```
img{
  width: 100%;
}
```

To center the element, I would use [this plugin](http://jquerydevbrazil.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/jquery.center.js). It makes you do no work, other than to call the function

```
$("img").center()
```

Comment: I am aware the blank spaces between the images is caused by the `margin-bottom`. I am trying to center the images INSIDE the `div`. The image cannot be distorted and it has to occupy all the space inside the `div` (100px height and 100px width).

Comment: No, as you can see on the second `div`, there is some space left. Because the width of the image is smaller than the width of the div.

Comment: @Derik How's this for you?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But it is still not filling up the `div`. If you add `background: black;` back to the `div` you'll easily see that.

Comment: You can't fill the div up anymore without distorting it. They should all be filling up width-wise. You can't add a height property, or they will distort

Comment: I know, that is exactly the problem. You got it, great =) But I'm sure that there's a way out, maybe with Javascript? EDIT: Because if you have `overflow: hidden` you can have the image to fill it up WITHOUT distorting.

Comment: @Derik There is no way to do it without distorting the image. The best you can do is center it and move on. And seeing how they are different sizes, you can't really do that either lol

Comment: Of course there is s way to do it. With Javascript you can do conditionals and it would be totally possible. I just have no idea how.

Comment: Really? Because if it was a `background-image` it would be easy. Kinda strange that there's no way to do it with a `<img>`.

Comment: I know it isn't. I'm sad that I can't do this one with just CSS. I'm a beginner on Javascript.

Comment: But you did not solve my problem. I still have the same problem. There are people with the knowledge to do it here, with Javascript for instance.

Comment: @Derik You can not fill up the div completely unless the picture is the same dimensions. It is not possible. No matter what language you use. That is why you center it. To make the problem less noticeable.

Comment: Yes it is possible, because you can overflow the image. So it fills everything up and overflows in the edges.

Comment: Then Mikel's faux crop fix is the only way you are going to accomplish it. If you want none of the image overflowing, but no distortion, that's impossible

Comment: I know. But I want the image to overflow. It has to. Otherwise it is impossible, as you said. But the image has to be centered. I want it to crop on the middle, not on the upper left side. The smallest dimension must be 100px.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `min-width: 100%` to the img. [Here's an example.](http://jsfiddle.net/mikemiketm09/q2c9D/1/) It may stretch the picture a little but at the size it is, may not be too noticeable. :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the image cannot be distorted. This is just and example, my real situation has bigger images and even higher difference between height and width.

Comment: Will all the images be bigger than the crop size? Or will some possibly be smaller than the width/height of the square?

Comment: Probably none of them will be smaller. I guess this makes thing a little easier? Thanks in advance.

Comment: That is interesting but there is too much being overflowed without need and it is not centered horizontally. Maybe the only way to deal with this is with Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

This will center the image on the page:

```
img{
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
}
```

Just wrap the images in a `<div>` to position them somewhere on the page.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I want the images to be centered, the problem is that I do not know which size the image will be. And it has to fill the entire `div`.

Answer (score 0):

The way i do it is set the width or height, but only 1 as 100%.

```
<img width="100%" src=""/>
```